# In Ember can you overwrite component functions using the component helper?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Still pretty new to Ember. I am trying to use the `component` Ember helper to overwrite a function on the component.

My component looks like:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  getValue() {...}
  ...
});
```

I have another component with a template that looks like:

```
<div>
  {{component myComponentName getValue=(action myCustomGetValue)}}
</div>
```

I would imagine that this would overwrite the `getValue` function from the original component, but it does not. Is this possible using this helper to do this? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass function references to `component` helpers in Emberjs.

You can call your component through `component` helper like:

```
{{component "my-component" getValue=(action "myCustomGetValue")}}
```

in which case you should define the custom action in your parent component or controller like:

```
actions: {
  myCustomGetValue(){
    return "my custom value";
  }
}
```

You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/0386cab78956ac1ab840f83d0719cf11) for this usage.

Comment: This did it! Thanks for the help